# i'm trying to print linked list reverse via recursion but it doesn't work

Tags: c, recursion, printing, linked-list

i tried to print linked list in reverse order via recursion.
this is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list {
    int value;
    struct list* next;
} list_s;

static int g_size=sizeof(list_s);

void printRe(list_s *node) {
    if (node = NULL)
        return;
    printRe(node->next); // this is where error happens
    printf("%d", node->value);
}

int main() {
    list_s *head;
    head = (list_s*)malloc(g_size);

    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    int i = 0;
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);

    head->value = x;
    head->next = NULL;

    list_s *current;
    current = head;
    for (i; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        current->next = (list_s*)malloc(g_size);
        current = current->next;
        scanf("%d", &x);
        current->value = x;
        current->next = NULL;
    };
    printRe(head);
    return 0;  
}
```

So as you see, the error occurs when I tried printing node->next. why did error occur? did i passed list to a function wrong way?

Thank you!

Comment: `node=NULL` should be `node==NULL` in that if-test.

Comment: `gcc -Wall` shouts `warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
     if(node=NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

if condition in printRe() function should be like

if(node==NULL) instead of if(node=NULL)

i hope it will help you.
Thanks